# how to add url on jquery ui object

Tags: jquery-ui

http://jsfiddle.net/bcAH2/5/

i am working on a simple project there are 12 objects that are sort able using jquery ui
how can i add link behind each block and enable it so if i double click it the link open in new tab

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default four">4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ul>
```

and the jquery function obviously

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: Usually you attach double-click behaviour with the [`dblclick` event handler](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/). What have you tried so far? You're not making it particularly clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: if u run the jsfiddle u can see i have 12 blocks 
i want to put website urls on those blocks and when user double click the block it opens the url
you know just like chrome home page 
but blocks open with double click instead of single click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the URLs to each `li` element as follows (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) for details on HTML5 custom attributes):

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" data-href="http://www.google.co.uk">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" data-href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" data-href="http://www.yahoo.co.uk">3</li>
    ...
```

Then use the [.dblclick()](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/) function in jQuery to capture the double click event, retrieve the URL behind the block and navigate to the URL:

```
$( "#sortable li" ).dblclick(function() {
    window.open( $(this).attr('href') );
});
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bcAH2/71/) for a Fiddle